# Objects deallocation question

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, dealloc

I have a code:

```
@interface PhotoListViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* firstPicContainer;
    IBOutlet UIImageView* secondPicContainer;
    UIImage* pic_one;
    UIImage* pic_two;
    IBOutlet UILabel* firstPicLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel* secondPicLabel;
    NSString* firstPicName;
    NSString* secondPicName;
    IBOutlet UILabel* authorLabelA;
    IBOutlet UILabel* authorLabelB;
    NSString* authorName;

}
@property (retain) UIImage* pic_one;
@property (retain) UIImage* pic_two;
@property (copy) NSString* firstPicName;
@property (copy) NSString* secondPicName;
@property (copy) NSString* authorName;


@end
```

The question is: should I release the whole pack of objects or just those, whose properties I've declared?
For example: firstPicName is NSString and is retained, when is set, its container is UILabel* firstPicLabel, which is  assigned like this:

```
firstPicLabel.text = firstPicName;
```

in -viewDidLoad. So label as an object is not retained by itself, its property does. The same thing is with other objects, properties are retained, others just a container. The owner of these containers is theirs view, which should be responsible for their release, but I'm slightly confused here, so I want to clarify that point.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't put underscores in ivar names or method names;  it looks out of place in comparison to the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  For any property that you declare as `retain` (or `copy`), you should set its value to `nil` in your `dealloc` method.  Properties that are declared on other objects and fields which you do not retain yourself you do not need to worry about.

Comment: Well, thats not exactly, what I was asking for :)

Comment: So, I do not need to worry about those labels and UIImageViews? Their properties are assigned by the value these declared properties, and because they are assigned, they shouldn't be explicitly released?

Comment: @Matubo - Then I'm not sure what you're asking for.  I thought you wanted to know which objects you need to release?  If so, then the answer is "only the properties that you've declared as retain/copy, and any other objects that you have manually retained in your code".

Comment: My reply was on your first version of answer, that was without the second phrase. :)

Comment: You can also just not worry about the difference and set all your properties to nil in your dealloc. If they're set as retain or copy then that'll cause the setter to release them. If they're set as assign then the setter won't do anything with respect to memory management.

Comment: But the matter of the problem is not in the properties, theay are definetely should be released as they are retained. I'm asking about other declared elements in iVars: UIImageViews, UILabels.

Comment: @Matubo please note that just because you declared a (retain) property in your interface file it does not mean you have to release it. You only release it IF and ONLY IF you have assigned something (an object) to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface will never provide enough information about what you should or shouldn't release (but it will provide clues).

You could have all the ivars and properties you declared above, but if you haven't initialised them and/or accessed their properties, there is never going to be an object to release in the first place.

Rule of thumb is:

**1) If you create, copy or retain an object, you are responsible for releasing it.**

**2) See rule #1 above.**

In practice, here are some examples:

```
@implementation...
...
pic_one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
...
@end
```

`pic_one` is declared as an ivar but is assigned to an autoreleased object. You don't have to release it.

Another example:

```
@implementation....
...
self.pic_one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
...
@end
```

You assigned this UIImage object via its assessor/property which is declared as retain, so you are responsible for releasing it. "Behind the scenes", here's what happens when you assign the object via its property (example is for properties declared as retain, copy will be slightly different but same principle).

```
- (void)setPic_One:(UIImage*)newImage
{
   if (pic_One != newImage)
   {
        [newImage retain];
        [pic_One release];
        pic_One = newImage;
   }
}
```

And a last one:

```
UIImage *testImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:@"test.png"];
self.pic_one = testImage;
[testImage release];
```

In this case you are alloc'ing/init'ing (creating) an UIImage object, so you are responsible for releasing it. At the same time you are also assigning it to a property declared as retain so it is your responsibility to release it too when you are done with it (usually in your dealloc method).

Comment: Yes, these are the basics of memory management, that are ABC to every starter. But the moment, that I want to clarify is:
firstPicContainer.image = self.pic_one;
UIImageView is declared in iVar, its property is assigned to a retained value. Should it then be released in -dealloc?

Comment: The problem is in the dualism of the situation: on one hand the property value is retained by me, the property 'image' of UIImageView is retained by iself: '@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image'. Everything shows, that I should release it. But on the other hand: I didnt break the memory rule: never used 'alloc''copy''new'functions to create an instance. And the UIImageView is owned by the view as its subview, so the view is responsible to release it, and I shouldnt. I'm really desperate.

Comment: To answer your first comment re: `firstPicContainer.image = self.pic_one`, firstPicContainer should not be released because you are not accessing it through its property but directly via the ivar. BUT because the firstPicContainer is also declared as an IBOutlet, it will be retained by the view when your nib is loaded (if you have connected it to an UIImageView object on Interface Builder). In this case you will have to release `firstPicContainer` because interface builder will access it via its property (and it is also recommended that you set it to nil on `viewDidUnload`).

Comment: In addition to the comment above, you should probably post an example with interface and implementation files to clarify what you are asking.